# Interchanging the extremes of integration line integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

Given an line integral involving a vector-valued function, is it possible to exchange the extremes of integration in the following way?
$\int_{A}^{B} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dl} =-\int_{B}^{A}  \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dl}$
A and B are points connected through a certain path

Comment: If this is correct, should I pay attention to something in particular?

Comment: Yes.  It is possible.

Comment: Just be careful that the orientation of thebunit tangent to the curve is consistent with the integration limits (i.e., don't double count).

Comment: Do you mean that, after interchanging A and B, the unit vector mantains the same orientation or not?

Comment: Yes.  If you multiply by $-1$ and interchange the limits, then don't change the orientation of the unit vector.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help

Comment: I'm a bit confused because in electrostatics my professor used to write $V(P)-V(Po)=\int_{P}^{Po} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} $ and then considered a path going from P to Po (our reference point). But, from the gradient theorem, I know that $V(P)-V(Po)=\int_{Po}^{P} \nabla(V) \cdot \vec{dl}=-\int_{Po}^{P} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl}$ with dl going from Po to P. Which one is correct?

Comment: My doubts arise because, after that iI swap the extremes of integration in the last integral, I still get that the unit vector goes from Po to P